# jQuery find text and write into another tag attribute with each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, find, each

..
Hello

I try to get the text from my `figcaption`-Element and insert into the corresponding `a`-Tag -> (`data-title`)

At the moment I find the figcaption and write it into the variable 'desc'. But every figcaption should be insert into the `data-title`from the link. Now only the last `desc` will be written into `data-title`.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mobilat/60mm991f/) and my `jQuery`-code:

```
jQuery('figure').find('figcaption').each(function (index) {
    var desc = $(this).text();
    //var desc = jQuery('figcaption').text();
    console.log(index + desc);
    jQuery('.lightbox2').attr('data-title', ''+ desc +'');
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the code and not the image of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the callback for `.text()`

```
$('figure figcaption').text(function(el, txt) {
    $(el).prev('a.lightbox2').attr('data-title', txt);
});
```

or the same for `attr()`

```
$('a.lightbox2').attr('data-title', function() {
    return $(this).next('figcaption').text();
});
```

Your code does work fine however, as long as you include jQuery in the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/60mm991f/1/

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm using the same for my `attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

```
$('a.lightbox2').attr('data-title', function(ele){
    return $(ele).closest('figure').find('figcaption').text();
})
```

You code will work with slight modification [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/166yma90/1/)

```
jQuery(this).prev('.lightbox2').attr('data-title', '' + desc + '');
```

instead of

```
jQuery('.lightbox2').attr('data-title', '' + desc + '');
```

Comment: thanks for your help .. your solution also works fine.